# iphone sdk addressbook - get ABRecordRef

Tags: iphone, addressbook

in the method

> `- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {`

im trying to simply access ABRecordRef as a variable, but i keep getting the error

> expected expression before 'ABRecordRef'.

I can already get names and company info, but not the ABRecordRef.

What I am doing is:

> NSLog(@"Contact Reference: %d", ABRecordRef);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

? And what do you mean by

```
contactRef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ABRecordRef];
```

? It doesn't make sense considering `ABRecordRef` is a type, not a number.

Comment: yeah, my .h has #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>.

I have working address book calls in the same method, just I can not access the ABRecordRef.

Comment: @norskben: is the 3rd piece of code in your question the implementation of `-peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:`?

Comment: i edited my 'what i am doing section' to make it simpler, what do i need to do to make NSLog(@"Contact Reference: %d", ABRecordRef); work?  the error is still error: expected expression before 'ABRecordRef'

Comment: @norskben: But still you can't put `ABRecordRef` there. It is a *type*, not a *number*. Do you mean `NSLog(@"Contact Reference: %d", person);`?

Comment: Thanks, it was solved when I replaced NSLog(@"Contact Reference: %d", ABRecordRef); with  NSLog(@"Contact Reference: %d", person);